# Convert string array "[1,2,3]" to array of number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been searching for a solution but I only found the convertion from `["1","2","3"]` to `[1,2,3]`, but my question is how to convert this: `"[1,2,3]"` to `[1,2,3]`.

It might be clear for many of you but for me not.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few ways:

- Using the already-mentioned: `eval("[1,2,3]")`
- Using the already-mentioned: `JSON.parse("[1,2,3]")`
  You can visit https://github.com/koldev/JsonParser and get the oficial implementation for browsers that don't have this method, like IE7.
- Using jQuery's JSON interpreter: `$.parseJSON("[1,2,3]")`
- Using the function constructor: `Function("return [1,2,3];")()`
- Using any constructor: `[]["filter"]["constructor"]("return [1,2,3]")()` (Thanks to [JSF*ck](http://www.jsfuck.com/))

The safest option is to use the JSON package, either from jQuery or your browser's native one.

Remember that `eval` is evil! It allows to execute arbitrary code.
The same goes for the `Function` constructors, but with those you can add `'return'` to it.
If you do `eval("[1,2,3]; evil();")`, the `evil()` function will execute, while `Function("return [1,2,3]; evil();")` will prevent the execution of `evil()`.
**This is not the perfect solution**, since one can still do `Function("return evil() || [1,2,3];")`, and `evil()` will be executed. But, in this case, `[1,2,3]` is only returned if `evil()` returns a falsy value (`""`, `null`, `0`, `false`, ...).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80082/discussion-on-answer-by-ismael-miguel-convert-string-array-1-2-3-to-array-of).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `JSON.parse("[1,2,3]");`

working example http://jsfiddle.net/bcguevd2/

Answer (score 5):

You could also parse it by yourself:

```
var s = '[1,2,3]';
var a = s.slice(1, -1).split(',').map(Number);
// .slice(1, -1) -> "1,2,3"
// .split(',')   -> ["1", "2", "3"]
// .map(Number)  -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Variation:

```
var a = (s.match(/-?\d+/g) || []).map(Number);
// .match(/-?\d+/g)     -> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

```
// '[]'.match(/-?\d+/g) -> null
// (null || [])         -> []
```

Comment: That's an interesting variation, but I suggest that you use `/\b(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b/g` instead.

Comment: Or `/\b(-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\b/g`, since Javascript allows for number to be written as `1.`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse("[1,2,3]")
```

Also you can use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) if the source is a trusted one([Don't use eval needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)) like

```
eval("[1,2,3]")
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Just remind that `JSON.parse` isn't supported by IE7- (a prayer to you all that still must support it), but there are shims for it (most notably, json2.js).

Comment: Why would you even suggest `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` *with the following caveat* [Don't use `eval` needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

```
var myArray = eval("[1,2,3]");
```

Comment: Using `eval` is generally a bad practice. *Always* warn about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Well, "[1,2,3]" is a String object.
    You need to deserialize it using JSON.parse().

    e.g: 
    var arr = "[1,2,3]"
    JSON.parse(arr)

    output will be >> [1,2,3]

Note: browser console don't detect JSON.parse() or JSON.stringify()
You have to do it in your code editor.
```